# How Create an event handler for event "resize"?

Tags: javascript

when alternating the display on the browser (F12) from mobile or responsive to desktop the div (content_filter) disappears.. refresh the page to fix the bug.

Desktop view

[image: Desktop mode]

from what I understand I need to add a Window: resize event to avoid refreshing each time.
my level in javascript is completely beginner.
can you show me the correct technique with my code?

```
<script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            jQuery(function ($) {

                $('.filter_btn').click(function (event) {
                    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                        $('.content_filter').slideToggle('250', 'swing', 'hide');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style >
        @media all and(max - width: 768 px) {
            .content_filter {
                display: none;
            }
        } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
console.log(window.innerHeight);
});
```

check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event
for further informaion.